# SQL Serverでパラメータ名指定のパラメータBindは可能でしょうか？

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

C#にてデータベース操作のプログラムを開発中です。
Oracleでは、OracleCommandのBindByNameをtrueに設定することで、パラメータ名指定による
パラメータ設定が可能と思いますが、SQL Serverでもこのようなオプションはありますでしょうか？
SQL Serverの場合、パラメータ名指定によるパラメータ設定が可能なのか教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

[パラメーターのプレースホルダーの使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#working-with-parameter-placeholders) で説明されていますが、

- `SqlCommand` = `@parameter`
- `OleDbCommand` = `?`
- `OdbcCommand` = `?`
- `OracleCommand` = `:parameter`

となります。